# What does mvn -pl do?

Tags: maven

What exactly happens during this command:

```
mvn -pl ABC  –am  -amd?
```

Does it compile the code?

The reason I asked is I have purposely put an invalid file and when I run `mvn -pl ABC -am -amd` option I get successful result and I'm confused why Maven is not complaining about the errored file?

But if I use `mvn install` command it errors!

Answer (score 62):

`-pl` or `--projects` allows you to select a specific set of projects to apply your goal, (e.g. `clean install`) this way saving the time you would spend waiting for a full build on a big project if you just need to build a couple modules.

You might wanna check the following section:

- [Specifying a Subset of Projects](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#_specifying_a_subset_of_projects)

Comment: Thanks Jhurtado, actually I'm using this complete command        mvn -pl Abc:Xyz  –am  -amd . The project ABC:XYZ has an invalid file in that and maven does not compalin

Answer (score 17):

- `-pl` makes maven build only specified modules and not the whole project (in this case it's only *ABC*).
- `-am` makes maven figure out what modules our target depends on and build them too(in this case it's *ABC*'s dependencies).

Comment: Also 'mvn -pl -my-submodule' will build all but the module you don't want to.

Answer (score 4):

If you say mvn -pl, and give no argument to -pl, you are asking maven to do absolutely nothing.

-pl assumes that you are sitting in a project with multiple modules, and want to build a subset. You just asked for the null subset.

Comment: Actually I'm using this complete command mvn -pl Abc:Xyz –am -amd . The project ABC:XYZ has an invalid file in that and maven does not compalin when I run it.

Answer (score -5):

You haven't actually given it a goal to run. `mvn -pl Abc:Xyz -am -amd` has two problems with it.
First of all, `-amd` implies `-am`, so you don't need both.
Secondly, you haven't given it a goal to run, like install, package, test, or compile.

Comment: `-amd implies -am, so you don't need both` -- I don't think this is right.  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Make+Like+Reactor+Mode gives an example in which both are used.  Also, `-am` triggers builds on my system which `-amd` does not.  Pretty new to this but AIUI `-am` builds projects that your project depends on, `-amd` builds projects that the projects your project depends on, depend on(!)

Comment: `-am` is kind of the opposite of `-amd`:  

E.g. when using mvn -pl abc  
`-am` also builds all modules which abc depends upon  
`-amd` also build all modules which depend on abc